# Huge page support on GCE

Tags: google-compute-engine, tlb, huge-pages

I'm running a JBOSS application that we have successfully configured use Huge Pages/Large Pages on with other cloud platforms other than GCE. But I'm having problems on GCE.  I'm seeing the error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve large pages memory req_addr: 0x00000005f0000000 bytes: 8858370048 (errno = 12).
```

when I start the JVM. These are running on Ubuntu 14.04 based systems, they have been configured just like similar systems we have huge pages working before, so I'm wondering if there is some settings on virtual machine level that aren't set correct to allow large pages to work. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just wasn't allocating enough huge pages to handle the amount of heap I was configured for the JVM. So there isn't a problem in GCE.